# adding log.e in the catch

Tags: android, performance, android-logcat

this is the error log that i get when i put Log.e in my catch,but i don't know what causes the error to occur.

```
try{
   ...
}
catch(IOException e ){
   Log.e("MY_APP_error!", "Error!", e);
}
```

here is the result of the my logcat

```
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825): Error!
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825): java.io.EOFException
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:579)
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:827)
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:283)
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at com.example.logintest.adduser$AssCrounTask.doInBackground(adduser.java:111)
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at com.example.logintest.adduser$AssCrounTask.doInBackground(adduser.java:1)
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-06 09:12:28.698: E/MY_APP_error!(4825):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: post doInBackground(adduser.java:111)

Comment: Hi,may i ask how do you know that line 111 causes error?...

Comment: Read the stacktrace, at com.example.logintest.adduser$AssCrounTask.doInBackground(adduser.java:111)

Comment: It is in the stacktrace you posted

Comment: What is readStream method? Post it

Comment: What do u expect as a result from the server? Its a PUT method.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno,I posted now the readStream

Comment: @kupsef,I tried PUT because POST method doesn't work,..same also result with the PUT just tested

Comment: Yeah but should be there any content in response?:) POST and PUT methods normaly does not have any response entity. Only header data.

Comment: With your current code you get the response and print it in the Log but don't do anything with it. But what is the problem now? I mean: you don't want to get the exception? I don't see any problem with this exception. It just say to you the response is finished

Comment: @MarcoAcierno is that not an error?

Comment: @kupsef,can you please show me what you mean i am confuse here.thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception `EOFException` (End Of File!) is throw when the reading (from a file or stream too) is finished.

You can ignore this exception if your code is OK with the fact it finished the reading (should, because it's obvious the file will finish)

> public class EOFException extends IOException
>
> Signals that an end of file or end of stream has been reached unexpectedly during input.
>
> This exception is mainly used by data input streams to signal end of
>   stream. Note that many other input operations

In your specific case, refer to the fact it finished to download a http request (a web page? more code if you need help)